# Customizing registration form joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla-2.5

I was actually customizing a registration form of my website, I needed to add an extra field for date of birth which I did using this [joomla_docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field)

Now I need to validate this field , I read this [doc](https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation)

but I couldn't understand how this custom validation part works , is there only one validate.js? . Where do I exactly add the code? It says after loading validate (What does it exactly mean?).

If I do anything with that validate.js itself , would it be a core code modification? (I found validate.js at system/js.validate.js but it's a minified file)

Answer (score 1):

**Use of validata.js** file is if you want to set the extra field as required one true and you can't fill the required field and click submit that time it will call the validate.js file and display the invalid form message.